# While loop articles - if statement order

Tags: posts, query-posts, get-posts, order

I want to show a list of articles, but I want to show in the 1st place my second article and after it the last.

*Eg: Article 1 Article 2 Article 3 Article 4 to be: Article 2 Article 1 Article 3 Article 4*

I'm using this while loop:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=35&offset=0' );
while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post();
$i++;
if ($i==2) {
echo 'Article2: '.the_title();
}
if ($i==1) {
echo 'Article1: '.the_title();
}
endwhile;
?>
```

But It render: Article1 Article2

I want to render this: Article2 Article1

Thank you in advance!

PS: I want to do this because I want different positions of articles (like CNN)
and I don't want to repeat WP_query for all my 34 articles on homepage... Because of this i use if statement.

If you think that this is not a good question please do not -1 me, I will delete my post if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepare the query before you loop over it:

```
$first  = array_shift( $the_query->posts );
$second = array_shift( $the_query->posts );

// now re-add in reverse order
array_unshift( $the_query->posts, $first );
array_unshift( $the_query->posts, $second ); // this is now the first item

while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); // regular loop
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately is not useful for me. I'm trying to make something like nyt.com . On my first column i want to show articles with offset: 1 3 4 5 6 7 and in my second collumn i want to show 2 8 9 10.

Comment: I don't want to repeat WP_Query (I have 34 articles on homepage)

Comment: This is exactly what you are asking for: it switches the first two items in your custom query.

Comment: yes, thank you... I will ask a new question with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the array of posts with $the_query->posts :

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=35&offset=0' );
    // swap post 1 with post 2
    $temp_post = $the_query->posts[0];
    $the_query->posts[0] = $the_query->posts[1];
    $the_query->posts[1] = $temp_post;
    while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query ->the_post(); ?>
       // do your regular loop
<?php endwhile; ?>
```